# Flutter app text turning to white when I set usematerial3: true in MaterialApp

Tags: android, flutter, dart, material-ui, material-design

I got excited when I was knowing that Google have introduced Material 3 for flutter apps. This means we can design Flutter Apps with Material 3 design, but when I code a UI for testing Material 3, whole texts and Icons colour share the same colour as the background colour in my App which means they're all white, example from screenshot:

[image: My App]

This is what I'm expecting about (I colored the text and icon for example):

[image: Layout I expected]

Anyone ever face this problem?

This is my main.dart "MaterialApp" code:

```
MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            useMaterial3: true,
          ),
          routes: AppRoute.routes,
          initialRoute: AppRoute.mainPageRoute,
        ),
```

and this is my tab code:

```
TabBar(
          tabs: const [
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.chrome_reader_mode),
              text: "List Hadits",
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              text: "Search Books",
            ),
          ],
          controller: _controller,
        ),
```

UDPDATE: Also, I'm using [material theme builder](https://material-foundation.github.io/material-theme-builder/#/) for defining my colour scheme:

```
ThemeData(
            useMaterial3: true,
            colorScheme: lightColorScheme,
          ),
          darkTheme: ThemeData(
            useMaterial3: true,
            colorScheme: darkColorScheme,
          ),
```

Comment: can you share your main.dart file

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property for `TabBar` Widget

```
 labelColor: Colors.blue, //<-- selected text color
 unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black, //<-- Unselected text color
```